# Cannot invoke contains(int) on the primitive type int

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with case 4. I'm trying to find a voter using ID. It's public and it says `Cannot invoke contains(int) on the primitive type int`. Why is that? The Id is literally public but I don't know the problem.

All I'm trying to do is to find the Id of the voter.

```
public class Voters {

    public static HashSet<Voter> voters = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("1. Add New Voter");
            System.out.println("2. List All Voters");
            System.out.println("3. Find a Voter By Name");
            System.out.println("4. Get information about specific voter");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            int chosen = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (chosen) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("National ID Number: ");
                int idNum = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("\nName: ");
                String name = scanner.next();
                System.out.print("\nMale Relative: ");
                String maleRelative = scanner.next();
                System.out.print("\nAge: ");
                int age = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("\nAddress: ");
                String address = scanner.next();
                System.out.print("\nProvince: ");
                String province = scanner.next();
                System.out.println("");
                Voter voter = new Voter(idNum, name, maleRelative, age, address, province);
                voters.add(voter);
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\YourPcName\\Desktop\\voters.txt");
                fileWriter.append("\n").append(voter.toString());
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                for (Voter v : voters) {
                    System.out.println(v);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Name: ");
                Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
                String n = ss.nextLine();
                System.out.println();
                for (Voter v : voters) {
                    if (v.name.contains(n)) {
                        System.out.println(v);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Id: ");
                Scanner nn = new Scanner(System.in);
                int s = nn.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                for (Voter v : voters) {
                    if (v.nationalIdNumber.contains(s)) {
                        System.out.println(v);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
            }

        }
    }

    static class Voter {
        public int nationalIdNumber;
        public String name;
        public String maleRelativeName;
        public int age;
        public String address;
        public String province;

        public Voter(int nationalIdNumber, String name, String maleRelativeName, int age, String address,
            String province) {
            this.nationalIdNumber = nationalIdNumber;
            this.name = name;
            this.maleRelativeName = maleRelativeName;
            this.age = age;
            this.address = address;
            this.province = province;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Id: " + nationalIdNumber + "  Name: " + name + "  Male Relative: " + maleRelativeName + "  Age: "
                    + age + "  Address: " + address + "  Province: " + province;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nationalId number is an int....you cant do int.contains(int)...

Either int == int... or String.valueOf(nationalIdNumber).contains(String.valueOf(yourInt))

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What does it mean for an int to “contain” another int?  Does 9 contain 3?  Does 10 contain 0?  Are you trying to compare them as strings, such that 12345 would contain 234?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nationalIdNumber` is of type `int` It does not have any methods. What are you trying to do? Maybe that line should read

```
if (v.nationalIdNumber == s) {
```

? I dont't know. Give us some more context.

Comment: If the question is unclear, you can leave a comment on the question asking for clarity. I think you need more rep though, I believe you need 30 rep to do that. Until you reach that, please refrain from leaving answers like this. Only leave an answer if it directly answers the question - no speculation or guesses. You only need 1 more upvote until you have enough rep.